# In a world with 12 moons but NO sun, how to define a day?

Tags: moons, astronomy, orbital-mechanics, alternate-worlds, sunlight

I made the map of my fantasy world before thinking about the physics, as you can see bellow the art!

I'm interested to understand how to decide which moon is in the sky at a given moment, if it's waning/waxing, how to define a day? 
People probably would use the Sun-like moon, the brightest as reference.

There is no sun. One of the moon is providing sun-like light, and actually most of the moons are glowing, like a full moon on earth.
This is a lone planet alone in en empty universe. No stars, no galaxies.
Orbit, moon dimensions is as pictured on the drawing bellow. 
So moons are small, and orbit close.

Looking forward your thoughts, and thanks for your time.

I have all the rights to use the map for commercial and private use, This map was created by the very talented Francesca Baerald, who illustrated all the maps of my world.

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding. Please take the [tour] and visit the [help] to better understand our community. You question is rather broad at the moment: you have just given the seed of an idea, and are asking us to come with details. This is not how this community work: you have to provide us as much details as possible and one specific problem, and then we will try to answer. Please rework your question accordingly.

Comment: @Juanito I would hazard a guess that this singular world in an empty universe is not of natural origin. In that case, it's difficult for anyone to figure out how orbits might work. In fact, I would go hard the other way: How does your creator deity want stuff to work? Also, you answer your own question: "People probably would use the Sun-like moon, the brightest as reference." You are probably going to have to elaborate on what other details you need.

Comment: This is WorldBuilding's [sandbox](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6168/sandbox-for-proposed-questions) - you just post your question *as an answer* to that meta post, and the community will help you improve it to fit the site's model. Welcome aboard :)

Comment: I hope this helps https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/referencing

Comment: Juanito - it's unfortunate that that's the way your first experience with our site and community went (I'd like to think we are typically friendly and welcoming ;) ).

Comment: Regarding the question - I recommend you split the part about lunar cycles ("when do they wax/wane?") to a different question, focusing on "what's day" in this question. Additionally, some details about the planet's and moons' size, their distances/orbits and what light sources are available should be enough to make this question suitable. It's perfectly fine to use rough definitions rather than strict measures (e.g. "the moons look as large as Earth's moon from the surface", rather than "the moons mean radius is 1737km"). The more  details you add, the better (as long as they're relevant).

Comment: If you commissioned an image, say that you commissioned an image. If you say "I made" and it is already published elsewhere, by someone else, you look like an art thief. Even if you are not, your choice of words made you look like one. And questions and answers with pictures and no [reference](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) are regularly downvoted here, pretty much every time, yes. Would you like your work plagiarized? If no, then you shouldn't be surprised that things looking like plagiarism are not appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

From a psychological, anthropological point of view, we define a *"day"* as the period of time where there is light, while the *"night"* is the period of time where there is darkness. To define the "day" of your universe, you must have in mind how much light there is on your planet. For example, in [Nightfall](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nightfall_(Asimov_novelette_and_novel)), the world was perpetuously iluminated by 6 different suns, so there was no concept of "night" or "day" - they simply counted time in other ways.

If there is not a big difference from when your *"sun"* moon is shining in the sky and when it is not the inhabitants of your world maybe don't have a concept of night/day cicle at all. If it's quite darker when your light-providing moon it's not in the sky, then this period of time will be the "night" and when it is it will be the "day".

Comment: On my own world of the game that I've created an alien race lives on rouge planet. Moons are too dark to be lumiscent. Hence I define a day as the own planets rotation around it's axis. Some far galaxies and night stars will periodically reappear.

Comment: @Majte How does one measure that? If it's a rogue planet astronomical references could bee difficult, no?

Comment: @ALambentEye Galaxies should be far enough away to be useful as [fixed stars](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fixed_stars) even for a rogue planet. Getting sufficient precision might be difficult, though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Rekesoft. Never heard of the book as well, will read it.